# Is there any technical difference between CSV, a TSV or a TXT file?

Tags: csv

I use these files constantly in my application, but aren't CSV, TSV or TXT files all **flat files**?
The content is:

```
"sample","sample"
```

Comment: They're all text files, yes.  You can view the contents of any of them to confirm that.

Comment: *but sometimes have a few upload errors* You should add some explanation, what is the content of the files? Maybe your users send files which had their extensions changed, or a comma is missing, there are many possibilities.

Comment: "a few upload errors" — What does that mean? Is there an error message? Does the wrong data get parsed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are all text files, following the same "guidelines". The difference between the files are - as long as the creator followed some "rules", that:

A `csv` file will have **c**omma **s**eparated **v**alues and a `tsv` file will have **t**ab **s**eperated **v**alues.

For .txt files, there is no formatting specified.

Comment: I think that calling these *specifications* is not accurate, IIRC there is no standard, norm, specification, etc. for these formats.

Comment: Yes, that's true. @A.L I've reworded it to guidelines - if you know a more fitting word - please let me know :-)

Comment: @A.L There’s [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) for CSV (informational but widely used, _e.g._ [by the W3C](https://www.w3.org/community/csvw/)) and a [spartan IANA registry spec](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/tab-separated-values) for TSV.

Answer (score 1):

.csv stands for comma separated values, .tsv stands for tab separated values.
As the names suggest, different elements in the file are separated by ',' and '\t' respectively.
The type is chosen depending on the data. If we have say numbers larger than 3 digits, we might need commas as part of the content ans it would be better to use a csv in that case.
Both are types of text files and are increasingly used for classification and data mining purposes.
They do not have any other technical distinguishing factor.

Comment: .CSV files might quote the strings so as to tolerate commas.

Answer (score 0):

A text file (which might have a `txt` file extension) will have lines separated by a platform specific line separator (CRLF on Windows, LF on Linux, and so on), and it will tend to contain characters human readable as text in some encoding.  Apart from that human readability expectation this allows pretty much any file content on some platforms, so this is more of a content classification than a specific file format.

The other two formats are usually considered special cases of a text file intended to allow easy automated processing; `tsv`, a "tab separated values" file is simpler than `csv`, a "comma separated values" file.

`csv` will have commas as field separators, and it may use quoting and escaping especially to handle commas and quotes occurring in those fields.  It may also include a header line as the first line in the file.  The last line in the file may or may not end with a line separator.
([Details](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2).)

`tsv` simply disallows tabs in the values, the header line is mandatory, the final line separator is mandatory.
([Details](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/tab-separated-values).)

A "flat file", in connection with databases, is a text file as opposed to a machine optimized storage method (such as a fixed size record file or a compressed backup file or a file using more elaborate markup language supporting data validation); a flat file tends to be `csv` or `tsv` or similar.

This answer benefited from a comment by Alex Shpilkin.